# Ran a command, not sure what I might have done? Wacom Tablet Removal Attempt

Tags: drivers, nvidia, tablet, wacom

Ran some commands from [this page](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/trusty/main/x/xserver-xorg-input-wacom/uninstall/index.html) in an attempt to remove the Wacom Tablet icon that comes with Ubuntu. It seemed to do a lot yet it's still there. I saw something from nvidia and a bunch of other things being messed with, any idea what I actually did?

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove xserver-xorg-input-wacom
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-wacom
sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-input-wacom
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Have you by any chance reviewed `man apt-get` It pretty clearly defines the supported options and what they do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you actually did:

You have performed actions on the [xserver-xorg-input-wacom package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=xserver-xorg-input-wacom&searchon=names)

I don't believe the `--auto-remove` switch you used in the first line is valid so it was likely ignored. As for the rest,

From the man page:

```
remove
           remove is identical to install except that packages are removed
           instead of installed. Note that removing a package leaves its
           configuration files on the system. If a plus sign is appended to
           the package name (with no intervening space), the identified
           package will be installed instead of removed.

       purge
           purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and
           purged (any configuration files are deleted too).
```